# What's the differenct among Model.objects, Model.objects(), and Model.objects.all() in mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, orm, mongoengine, database

Just as title described.When we have a mongoengine model as below:

    `class Model(Document):
        some fields definition~~`

And I added some items to the database by the Model, when I want to traversal all items, there are three ways, and which should I use?
The first:

    `for model in Model.objects:
        do something to model~~`

The second:

    `for model in Model.objects():
        do something to model~~`

The third:

    `for model in Model.objects.all():
        do something to model~~`

It seems that the three ways performed the same~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question! This is my opinion:

All of them are similar when you want to get all documents in a collection. All of them return a queryset that you can iterate on it. But, if you want to filter the result, you should use **objects()**. Like this:

```
for model in Model.objects(first_name='John', last_name='Doe'):
    do something to model~~
```

The **ojbects.all()** is pretty use-less in my opinion and is added to completeness because there is a symmetric **objects.first()** method. Maybe in some conditions, using **objects.all()** is explicit and more readable.

If you want to get a range of documents you can use array-slicing syntax with **objects** that looks really good and readable.

```
for model in Model.objects[10:20]:
    do something to model~~
```

Without using array-slicing syntax with **objects**, it is a real pain to determine a range:

```
for model in Model.objects().skip(10).limit(20):  # not recommended
    do something to model~~
```

In essence, **objects.all()** is use-less or used for readability, **objects** is good for getting all documents and or a range of documents and **objects()** is good for restricting the returned documents with some filters.

Have a good day!